# How do I convert date to the string in go using locale?

Tags: date, go, locale

I convert date to a string this way:

```
d.Format("Mon 02. Jan")
```

and I get something like

```
Fri 27. Jan
```

How can I switch the locale and get the string in other language?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't. The Go standard library does not contain localized month, day and zone names. The names are wired into the `time` package.

For example, the name of the months returned by [`Month.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Month.String) are stored in the unexported `time.month` global variable:

```
var months = [...]string{
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
}

func (m Month) String() string { return months[m-1] }
```

Similarly, names of weekdays come from [`Weekday.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Weekday.String), stored in unexported variable `time.days`.

Having said that, there may be 3rd party libraries supporting your needs. Here's an incomplete one which might be of  some help to you: https://github.com/mattbaird/go-i18n-formats

As shared by Igor Chubin below, this 3rd party lib is much more complete: https://github.com/klauspost/lctime

Also note that while providing a general, multilingual time formatting package is not an easy task, if you really need it, you could take the `time` package, copy it to your project and just translate the names to the language you need.

Also note that supporting a low number of languages and low number of layouts, it's easy to create the formatting yourself.

For example, the code below formats a given `time.Time` value in Hungarian, using the layout you used in your question:

```
func Format(t time.Time) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s %02d. %s",
        days[t.Weekday()][:3], t.Day(), months[t.Month()-1][:3],
    )
}

var days = [...]string{
    "Vasárnap", "Hétfő", "Kedd", "Szerda", "Csütörtök", "Péntek", "Szombat"}

var months = [...]string{
    "Január", "Február", "Március", "Április", "Május", "Június",
    "Július", "Augusztus", "Szeptember", "Október", "November", "December",
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(Format(time.Now()))
```

Output on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/exJBNBNqxr):

```
Ked 10. Nov
```

Output on my local machine:

```
Pén 27. Jan
```

Comment: I can't believe it is so bad. Are there no robust i18n packages for go?

Comment: @IgorChubin Unfortunately there's none yet (that I know of). But to support a specific language and layout, it's easy enough. Added to the answer.

Comment: I've found this library: https://github.com/variadico/lctime and it seems to have the features that I need. Thank you icza!

Comment: @IgorChubin Good find! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Unfortunately https://github.com/klauspost/lctime has been archived. It looks like this is the most active fork right now: https://github.com/InstaConsultInc/lctime.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a replacer as quickfix for the problem.
Example in german:

```
r := strings.NewReplacer(
            "January", "Januar",
            "February", "Februar",
            "March", "März",
            "April", "April",
            "May", "Mai",
            "June", "Juni",
            "July", "Juli",
            "August", "August",
            "September", "September",
            "October", "Oktober",
            "November", "November",
            "December", "Dezember", )


time := inputTime.Format("2 January 2006")

outputString := r.Replace(time)
```